# Django form text field not displaying

Tags: python, html, django

I have used django's models and forms to add a comment section to a blog app, however the form's text field will not show when loaded in the in the browser. Only the submit button loads with no textfield to submit with.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django import forms

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField("date published", default=datetime.now())

    def _str_(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    def _str_ (self):
        return self.text
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comment
from django.db import models

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        models = Comment
        exclude = ['post']

form = CommentForm
```

post.html

```html
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <h5>New comment</h5>

        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <br>
            <button class="btn" style="background-color:lightblue" type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .forms import CommentForm
from .models import Comment

def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('/blog/<int:pk>', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {"form":form})
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)

form = CommentForm()
```

In django's admin i can add new comments and the form loads as expected there but does not work on the blog post itself. Admin submitted comments through the admin panel are also saving and displaying fine.

Comment: this looks okay, 
could you share the view where you initialize and add the form to the context, 
should be something like context['form'] = CommentForm()`

Comment: I added the views.py. I'm new to coding and this file probably confuses me the most with regards to this.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in **forms.py**

change `models` to `model`

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comment
from django.db import models

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Comment # changed from models
       exclude = ['post']
```

in **views.py**

you are missing imports

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,redirect
from .models import Post
```

other changes
in your **models.py**
the **to string** method for classes is `__str__` not `_str_`

with this changes i was able to reproduce [this django project](https://github.com/danleyb2/so-56619081) with your snippets that works in posting comments

Comment: Thanks, i changed it but it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @HarryWhitnear have updated with where you should fix and created a working demo, hope it helps